# Angular2: Error while creating new component via CLI

Tags: angularjs, macos, angular, terminal, command-line-interface

Using Angular2, after moving in the project folder, I get in this error while trying create a new component via CLI, I'm going to post all terminal messages:

```
edoardocanti$ ng generate component other
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system          
events.
Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
installing component
create src/app/other/other.component.css
create src/app/other/other.component.html
create src/app/other/other.component.spec.ts
create src/app/other/other.component.ts
Cannot read property 'read' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'read' of undefined
at InsertChange.apply (/Users/edoardocanti/first-     
app/node_modules/@angular-cli/ast-tools/src/change.js:96:20)
at /Users/edoardocanti/first-app/node_modules/@angular-cli/ast-  
tools/src/change.js:71:61
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

It creates the folder of my new component but I have to add manually it in the app.module.ts, but however it works.

The real problem is when I try to create a new component inside an existing folder, in this case Angular doesn't create any new component.

Comment: I have been bitten by this as well, yet the same version of angular-cli works fine for another of my projects, created a few days ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you on 1.0.0.beta15 of angular-cli? If so, `npm install -g angular-cli@latest`. The problem seems to be gone in beta16

Answer (score 1):

make sure you cd into the app folder (just in case, from your sample it didn't seem), if not, try...

Check the version and make sure you are on latest:

```
ng -v
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.16
node: 6.2.0
os: darwin x64
```

Remove old and install new:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm remove cache
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

if you have an existing project:
may also need to remove node_modules
look everywhere for beta.15 and replace with beta.16

change angular-cli.json: "version": "1.0.0-beta.16",
package.json:
"devDependencies": {
"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.16",